# What are the steps used in this function used to calculate the Fibonacci sequence?

Tags: javascript, loops, fibonacci

```js
let a = 0;
let b = 1;
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  var c = a + b;
  a = b;
  b = c;
  console.log(c);
}
```

So I have this little code that apparently works and that gives the sequence of Fibonacci but I still don't understand how the code does its thing so I think need a visual representation with numbers to understand.

Comment: Code just do exactly what Fibonacci algorithm tells to do.

Answer (score 0):

Work through it step-by-step:

```
let a = 0;
let b = 1;
```

Self-explanatory variable assignment.

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {...}
```

Iterate from `1` to `10` with `i` storing the current iteration

```
var c = a + b;
```

Make a variable `c` set to `a` + `b`.

```
a = b;
b = c;
```

Set `a` to `b` and `b` to `c` - makes new base values for next iteration.

This example shows all the variables:

```js
let a = 0;
let b = 1;
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  var c = a + b;
  a = b;
  b = c;
  console.log(`a: ${a}, b: ${b}, c: ${c}, i: ${i}`);
}
```